# Getting attr value and

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's what I'm trying to do:

I make a GET request with jquery, and need the response.

In the response there is a dynamic variable that contains an array of values where I need to get a single value

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://site.com",
            success: function(response) {
                $("#price").html(response);
                var price = ("#price").(".item").attr("item-id");
                console.log(price);

            }
        });
```

For example what I am trying to get in the response is

```
<script>
   Item568 = {
                id: "568",
                name: "Pants",
                cost: "56"
            };

</script>
```

How can I get the cost value "56" from the response of a GET request? Thanks

Here is a example of the response:

```
<div class="item" item-id="568">
```

I need to take item-id value, then find the dynamic variable name on the page as above. (Item568)

Comment: please show us an example for response

Comment: Your question is a bit messy, I don't understand my answer anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your webservice retrieves this JSON :

```
        {
            id: "568",
            name: "Pants",
            cost: "56"
        }
```

NB : if your answer is the example you shown, this is not JSON, you should consider returning some json without the  tag whose presence is a none sense if what you request is a webservice.

You should set the dataType of your request to 'json', then you can access to the cost attribute which makes it like that :

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://site.com",
            success: function(response) {
                console.log('Your cost is: '+response.cost);
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming the variable is global you may use:

```
window['Item'+$('.item',$('#price')).attr('item-id')];
```

to get a member of the object, e.g. cost:

```
 window['Item'+$('.item',$('#price')).attr('item-id')].cost;
```